# How can I use SystemMediaTransportControls in Go?

Tags: windows, go, windows-runtime, media

I would like to read from Windows, playback information.
I have now tried several things in Go, but without success to get the information.

I have tried to include the UWP WinRT Api to access the GlobalSystemMediaTransportControls to read the playback information.
Also, I talked a lot with ChatGPT but all of it didn't make sense or made up librarys that don't exist.

Does anyone of you have experience how to implement this in Go?